# RSSOwl 2.2.1 won't run or install on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-mate, rss

I'm unable to install RSSOwl 2.2.1 since upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, when trying to install the .deb file I'm faced with Libhunspell 1.3 dependancy (Ubuntu 18.04 uses 1.6), and trying to use the zipped version gives me an error: RSSOwl was unable to create a browser for reading news.

Can anyone help me with that? [RSSowl.org](http://www.RSSowl.org/)

Edit: 
After installing Oracle JDK, I'm faced with this error message:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    /home/username/.rssowl2/config221/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/23/1/.cp/libswt-gnome-gtk-3735.so: libgnome-2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    no swt-gnome-gtk in java.library.path
    /home/username/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gnome-gtk-3735.so: libgnome-2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Can't load library: /home/username/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gnome-gtk.so
```

Comment: Might be a good time to switch rss clients: see the note at the base of this developer's page: https://github.com/rssowl/RSSOwl

Comment: Is firefox installed?, Also which JRE are you using?

Comment: @AmithKK Yes Firefox 61 is installed, and I have openjdk-8-jre 8u171

Comment: @MuaadElSharif Ah the version of SWT bundled with openjdk-8 doesn't seem to work with RSSOwl so you'll have to install the Oracle JDK

Comment: I've tried your solution and it didn't work, rebooted and removed openjdk, still the same result, any other suggestions?  @AmithKK

Answer (score 1):

> **NOTE:** You probably shouldn't continue using RSSOwl as there exists [multiple vulnerabilites](https://github.com/rssowl/RSSOwl) that will
>   never be patched as the project is no longer going to be mantained.
>   Furthermore it does not support Java9.

Having said that, the following prerequisites are required to run RSSOwl as The `.deb` package is for an older version of Ubuntu/Debian and can't be used:

- A working installation of firefox
- The Oracle JDK/JRE 8, that you can install by

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default`